# DynamoDBContext query .NET: No results until the result enumeration is manually inspected or converted to List

Tags: c#, asp.net, amazon-dynamodb, persistence

I'm using DynamoDBContext persistence model to Query the DynamoDB using a secondary local index from a composite table. I'm processing the return value to check to see which results match my criteria.

The issue is that the context `Query` is doesn't show the data until it's manually inspected. When the code runs normally, it returns no results. But when I put a breakpoint in the code (using VS), I check the results returned the first time and it says *Enumeration yielded no results* (i.e. no data). Then I wait for a few seconds and check the results again and now I see the results. When I continue execution now it works as expected because the results are there.

Here's the code:

```
[DynamoDBTable("UserTable")]
public class TableEntry
{
    [DynamoDBHashKey] // Indexed
    public string name { get; set; }
    [DynamoDBRangeKey] // Indexed
    public string id { get; set; }
    [DynamoDBProperty]
    public int numUsers { get; set; }
}


DynamoDBContext context = new DynamoDBContext(DynamoDBClient.client);
IEnumerable<TableEntry> entries = context.Query<TableEntry>(name, new DynamoDBOperationConfig { IndexName = "name-index" });
int num = entries.Count(entry => entry.numUsers > 0);
```

If I run the code without any breakpoints, it I get 0 for `num` always. However if I put a breakpoint in the code and then then inspect `entries`, it always shows empty the first time, then the second time I check it shows the results. The data just seems to be missing if I don't manually check the value of `entries`. I've tried putting a delay to give it time to populate but it doesn't help, unless I put a breakpoint and manually force VS to read the value 2 times, it doesn't show any results.

According to the Context Query [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/DotNetDynamoDBContext.html):

> This returns a collection of Reply objects. The Query method returns a "lazy-loaded" IEnumerable collection. It initially returns only one page of results, and then makes a service call for the next page if needed. To obtain all the matching items, you need to iterate only over the IEnumerable.

However if I convert the IEnumerable to a List it works fine without any issues:

```
 List<TableEntry> entries = context.Query<TableEntry>(name, new DynamoDBOperationConfig { IndexName = "name-index" }).ToList();
```

In my code I iterate through the results to count the number of objects, shouldn't that force the IEnumerable object to completely load it's data? So why is the Query not returning results until I manually inspect the values *twice* or convert it a List?